# Given $a, b, c$ are real numbers satisfying $ab + bc + ca \ge 2$...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $a, b, c$ be three real numbers satisfying $ab + bc + ca \ge 2$.
Find the minimum value of $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$.

Is there a general way to approach problems like these?

Comment: [Lagrange_multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)?

Comment: Are you sure the statement is complete and correct? Just let $a = 0, b=\frac{2}{c}, c\to -\infty$, then $a^3+b^3+c^3 \to -\infty$

Comment: Sorry guys, my mistake. The question was to ask for the minimum of the sum of the squares of a, b, and c, not the cubes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it's not that hard. Notice that

$$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca = \frac{1}{2}[(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2] \geq 0$$

So:

$$a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq ab+bc+ca \geq 2$$

This value is attained when $a=b=c=\pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$.

Comment: $a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq ab+bc+ca $ is also an immediate consequence of the rearrangement inequality.

Comment: Also of sum of three binary iAM-GM inequalities: $a^2+b^2 \ge 2ab$ etc.

Comment: In these kinds of problems, can you assume that a, b, and c are equal?

Comment: @Randy, certainly not. You can guess that the minimum value occurs when $a=b=c$, but you still have to prove the inequality for any possible choice of $(a,b,c)$.